# What aircraft can I fly?

Tags: lock-on-flaming-cliffs

*The question is about the Digital Combat Simulator, part of the Lock On: Flaming Cliffs series.  I was reading their FAQs and some forum posts, couldn't find a clear answer.*

Are K-50 (in DCS Black Shark) and A-10 (in Warthog) the *only* flyable aircraft?

I was reading about online compatibility to "Flaming Cliffs 2", but found no statement about upgrading any of the two DCS games over an existing "Flaming Cliffs 2" installation. Would this unlock more flyable aircraft?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently DCS only has two simulations, the Ka-50 Black Shark sim and the A-10C Warthog sim.

However, Flaming Cliffs 2 has network compatibility with DCS: Black Shark.  This means that a DCS: Black Shark player can play multiplayer missions in the same server as someone with Flaming Cliffs 2.  This doesn't mean that you get the better flight models in other aircraft however.  A player flying a Flaming Cliffs 2 Su-27 will be using the old flight model and easy avionics.  Additionally, each installation is a separate installation and separate program, so you can't install them all over one another.

I do want to add that I'm unsure as to whether or not DCS: A-10C is compatible with Flaming Cliffs 2.  I've been unable to find anything confirming that and I don't generally play online myself so I couldn't say one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

With the Introduction of DCS:World, depending on what modules you buy, an A-10, KA-50, F-15, various russian fighters, Su-25T are available.  Tanks from various countries are also available.

DCS:World forms a common infrastructure for each of those modules.  So, it's completely possible to be a JTAC in an M1A1 providing information to another player flying an A-10  overhead.